# Is it safe to "sign" a message with such a zk proof

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, hmac, mac

I am building an application in which I need to sign a message without revealing my entire identity.

To do so, I just compute a zk proof with the following purpose:

- prove I own the secret key **sk** associated with a public key **pk** (that matches some properties, e.g. $pk \in Authorized\_keys$)
- sign a message with $sig = H(sk|msg)$

with $H$ a hash function.

1. Is it safe ?
2. Should I use a more advance construction (such as $sig = H(sk \oplus opad, H(sk  \oplus ipad$, msg)) to build a HMAC) ?

Comment: Are you trying to design a [ring signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_signature)?

Comment: I am trying to design something close to a group signature. But even if my approach is not the right one, it would be helpful to understand why it does not work

Comment: What you are saying seems to describe attribute based signature. You can google it. For the specific case of $pk \in Authorized_keys$, it is called Ring-Signatures. You do not need to reinvent the wheel. I am pretty sure, they would be more efficient than generating ZK-Proofs on hashes

Comment: I am using such a structure because I want another property, which is the following: If I sign a message, the signature is deterministic, so that if someone else in the authorized keys tries to sign the same message, the signature will be different from mine. Given two signatures and the same message, I want to be able to tell if they come from the same person or not, which is not guaranteed by the ring signature from my understanding (but I might be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are severe performance restrictions it would always be safer to use HMAC or even a KDF such as HKDF(-extract). Note that e.g. SHA-2 is not secure for length extension attacks in case the hash is used as a keyed PRF. This is especially important if a message is being signed.

If you go for a KDF it might be a good idea to include an $\mathit{Info}$ field that specifies the use case (i.e. a label `"zk_proof_of_possession"` in ASCII). It could be that a salt and/or a message sequence number may increase security, but that's hard to know without understanding the full protocol.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the protocol I described can in deed be considered as a signature protocol ?

Comment: Well, it is a MAC as you cannot use $\mathit{pk}$ to verify, right? Sometimes MAC's are considered "symmetric signatures". Note that I didn't go into the ZK-proof part at all, maybe that's required and in that case somebody should come by and pinch me for getting it wrong...

Comment: No you can't but in this case I want to use the ZKP to: (1) prove that the MAC is correct and corresponds to a certain private key. (2) Ensure some properties associated with this private key, e.g. if I prove in the same ZKP that sk corresponds to a known public key pk, then could it be considered as a signature protocol ?